# Tweak default permissions in CAJA browser

Tags: permissions, caja

Newly created files and directories with the CAJA browser (e.g. in MATE desktop in Debian 9) seem impervious to whatever umask setting you set in /etc/profile.

Where can I change the default permissions of the newly created files and directories by the CAJA browser?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're login shell is Bash, setting `umask` at the end of `~/.bashrc` changes default permissions of new items created by Caja as well as everywhere else in your userspace. Depending on what's present on your system, adding the setting instead to the end of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` should have the same effect.

For other shells, adding the setting to the appropriate shell initialization file should have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you, David, but it doesn´t work. The empty directories and files created from caja still ignore it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I tested on my own machine before posting, but I'm running Fedora with Xfce rather than Debian with MATE, so that could be the difference.

Comment: Incidentally, did you log out and log back in before testing in Caja? That would be necessary for the change to take effect.